# c++ builder TService setup

Tags: windows-services, c++builder, vcl

I have build a TService application on c++ builder 2009 and I want to setup the service. I tried with InstallShield Premier, but I didn't manage to setup the service. Can anyone guide me through it?

So far I tried just to run the exe file but nothing happened. Then I built a setup with InstallShield, but when I run setup....nothing! I found a tut for InstallShield and Services, but it was saying something about Component in View list, that I didn't find.
At last, I tried the installutil command , but I get the message : installutil not recognised as internal command.

Answer (score 3):

To install a service all you need to do is run the following command from a command prompt or from the run command dialog.

```
C:\MyService.exe /install
```

To uninstall the service:

```
C:\MyService.exe /uninstall
```

Replace MyService.exe with your service filename.

Once the services is installed you can edit the service settings in the Windows Service Manager.  To access this, run the following from the run dialog or command prompt.

```
SERVICES.MSC
```

If you want to debug your service from within C++Builder, you need to create a application wrapper for it (there may be other ways to debug your service but this is the only way I have managed to do it).